# Statistics on exploited vulnerabilities

Tags: security

Where can I find statistics with the most common exploited vulnerabilities (such as buffer overflows) in software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) have a [top ten](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project) list - they track web applications, so may not be exactly what you are looking for.